# how to simulate Command + shift + esc on Mac using JS?

Tags: javascript, macos

I want to simulate that Command + Shift + esc is pressed together to stop screen recoding on MAC if its running on my web app using JS

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `keydown` event listener to your document.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  // Check that the key that is down is the “Escape” key
  // And that the meta key is down (cmd on Mac, the windows key on Windows)
  // And that the shift key is also down
  if (event.key === 'Escape' && event.metaKey && event.shiftKey) {
    // Do things!
  }
});
```

Comment: I need to simulate as the user Already press them, to cancel the effect if he already starting recoding the screen

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. This will detect when the “Escape” key is pressed if the command and shift keys are being held down. You can’t detect actions that are happening outside of your webpage.